# mitmproxy device identification

Tags: security, proxy

Currently am experimenting with mitmproxy. I have a setup where I can see all the traffic that is running through. I have multiple mobile devices (ios and android). I have installed the mitm certificate on each of them.

My question is, I would like to identify the request made by each of these. I would like to know whether a certain request came from device x or device y.

Am thinking of installing some kind of client certificate which I would later identify on the server. Is this a correct approach??

Any suggestion on how to tackle this problem? Any article or advice is welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A client cert won't work, because the device won't know to provide it.  What's wrong with just using the source IP?  You can correlate that to a device, long-term, with the DHCP logs and MAC address.

Comment: The source ip of a device might change from time to time. Device might be connected to a mobile network or wifi. Is it possible to correlate dhcp, mac address with the device?? Is there a better way?

Comment: You're going to try and trombone device traffic through a MitM proxy regardless of where it's connected to?  Madness.

Comment: Kinda crazy, but was looking for easier/smarter solution ...

Answer (score 0):

How about starting two mitmproxy processes listening on different ports (`--port`) and using for device A the 1st and device B the 2nd process as the proxy.